# Проверка содержимого буфера обмена

Tags: c#

Как можно проверить содержит ли буфер обмена текст, картинку или ссылку?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Есть класс [Clipboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx), этот класс позволяет работать с буфером обмена.

[Пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard.getdata(v=vs.110).aspx) проверки данных в буфере:

```
// After this line executes, IsHTMLDataOnClipboard will be true if
// HTML data is available natively on the clipboard; if not, it 
// will be false.
bool IsHTMLDataOnClipboard = Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.Html);

// If there is HTML data on the clipboard, retrieve it.
string htmlData;
if(IsHTMLDataOnClipboard)
{

    htmlData = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);

}
```

Так же есть методы `ContainsImage` и `ContainsText`, которые проверяют наличие картинки или текста в буфере обмена.